# Substitution is Pullback

Tags: category-theory, type-theory

I've read [here](http://math.andrej.com/2012/09/28/substitution-is-pullback/),
[here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/categorical+model+of+dependent+types)
and [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/substitution) about how to interpret pullbacks as the substitution of a term into a predicate or dependent type, such as $y:C⊢B(f(y)):Type$ being the pullback of the function $y:C⊢f(y):A$ and predicate $x:A⊢B(x): Type$.

What I do not understand is that all interpretations require two different "kinds" of arrows: one is a vanilla function, the other a predicate/dependent type. When I look at the starting diagram $A \rightarrow_f C \leftarrow_g B$ for a pullback, I just see two arrows $f$ and $g$.

I initially thought that functions and predicates/dependent types are actually interchangeable. For example, $y:Nat⊢Vector(y):Type$ is equivalent to $y:Vector⊢length(y):Nat$.

My issue then is that a pullback can be expressed in two ways; to re-use the above example, the pullback is both $y:C⊢B(f(y)):Type$ and $y:B⊢C(g(y)):Type$ (where $g$ is defined in the equivalence $x:A⊢B(x): Type \equiv x:B⊢g(x):A$). How to reconcile these two and prove equality?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you think $y:Nat\vdash Vector(y):Type$ is "equivalent" to $y:Vector\vdash length(y):Nat$? The first judgment states that $Vector : Nat\to Type$, while the second judgment simply states that $length : Vector \to Nat$. These not only aren't saying the same thing, they can't both hold as the second judgment requires $Vector : Type$ which is contradicted by the first judgment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused about the whole interpretation of judgments as objects and arrows. Let me try to make it clearer.

Suppose $\vdash C : \mathit{Type}$ and $\vdash A : \mathit{Type}$ are valid judgments. Their interpretations are respectively the objects $C$ and $A$.

Then we can form the judgment $y : C \vdash A : \mathit{Type}$. Since the context contains the variable $y : C$, its interpretation is an arrow with codomain $C$. The domain is the object that corresponds to the judgment $\vdash \Sigma_{y : C}\, A : \mathit{Type}$, i.e. the product $C \times A$. Therefore the interpretation is the projection $\pi_1\colon C \times A \to C$. Of course, we also have the projection $\pi_2 \colon C \times A \to A$.

Then, we suppose $y : C \vdash f(y) : A$ is a valid judgment. Its interpretation is an arrow $f \colon C \to C \times A$ that is a section of $\pi_1 \colon C \times A \to C$, i.e. $\pi_1 \, f = 1_C$.

Finally, suppose $x : A \vdash B(x) : \mathit{Type}$ is a valid judgment. Since the context contains the variable $x : A$, its interpretation is an arrow with codomain $A$. The domain is the object that corresponds to the judgment $\vdash \Sigma_{x : A}\, B(x) : \mathit{Type}$, that we shall denote by $\Sigma_A\, B$. Then the interpretation is the projection $\pi_1 \colon \Sigma_A\, B \to A$.

Now, we are interested in the arrows $\pi_2 \, f \colon C \to A$ and $\pi_1 \colon \Sigma_A\, B \to A$. If we form the pullback of these two arrows we get an object $\Sigma_C\, f^* B$ together with two morphisms $\pi_1\colon \Sigma_C\, f^* B \to C$ and $h\colon \Sigma_C\, f^* B \to \Sigma_A\, B$ satisfying the universal property.

$\pi_1\colon \Sigma_C\, f^* B \to C$ corresponds to the judgment $y : C \vdash B(f(y)) : \mathit{Type}$. It is the pullback of $\pi_1 \colon \Sigma_A\, B \to A$ along $\pi_2\, f$ and indeed it corresponds to the substitution into $x: A \vdash B(x) : \mathit{Type}$.

$h\colon \Sigma_C\, f^* B \to \Sigma_A\, B$ corresponds to the judgment $z : \Sigma_{y: C}\, B(f(y)) \vdash \langle f(\pi_1(z)), \pi_2(z)) \rangle : \Sigma_{x: A}\, B(x)$. It is the pullback of $\pi_2\, f$ along $\pi_1$ and indeed it corresponds to the weakening of the judgment $y : C \vdash f(y) : A$ with respect to the judgment $x : A \vdash B(x) : \mathit{Type}$, since it contains the void information that if $z : \Sigma_{y: C}\, B(f(y))$ then $\pi_2 (z) : B(f(\pi_1(z)))$.

Comment: I'm still digesting but in the meanwhile can you confirm what you mean by the projection $\pi_1 \colon \Sigma_A\, B \to A$ in context of $\Sigma_A\, B$? Is $\Sigma_A\, B$ just $A \times B$? Are you referring to the product projection?

Comment: I called it "projection" because one thinks of it as the map sending $\langle a, b \rangle : \Sigma_A\, B$ to $a : A$. But in this situation $\pi_1$ is just the intepretation of the judgment $x : A \vdash B(x) : \mathit{Type}$, we don't know anything else about it. Notice that here we suppose that we already know the interpretations of $\vdash C : \mathit{Type}$, $\vdash A : \mathit{Type}$, $y : C \vdash f(y) : A$ and $x : A \vdash B(x) : \mathit{Type}$, and what we want to find out is the interpretation of $y : C \vdash B(f(y)) : \mathit{Type}$.

Comment: $\Sigma_A\, B$ is not the product $A \times B$, because there is no object corresponding to $B$. Indeed, $B$ is a dependent type, so again, the interpretation of $x : A \vdash B(x) : \mathit{Type}$ is an arrow (having as codomain the interpretation of $A$, which is a simple type), not an object. If $B$ does not depend on $A$ (i.e. $\vdash B : \mathit{Type}$ is valid, and so $x : A \vdash B : \mathit{Type}$ is valid), then what I called $\Sigma_A\, B$ would be the product $A \times B$, just as we formed the product $C \times A$ for the judgment $y : C \vdash A : \mathit{Type}$.